# Lowering Voltage from 24V to 20V

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-design

What would be the most appropriate way to lower a 24V voltage in my circuit to a 20V supply voltage for my differential amplifier?

I imagine resistors wouldn't be suitable if the op-amp Vout is always changing.

Would a regulator, etc work?

Comment: a regulator or DC converter is pretty well the only way.

Comment: A schematic would be a good idea. The poor wording of your question makes me unsure whether you think that the supply pin is an input to your amplifier. Are you trying to reduce the supply voltage?

Comment: "input for my differential amplifier" usually means the signal input - do you in fact mean you want 20 volts for the local DC supply voltage for your diff amp?

Comment: @Andyaka, yes, sorry, that is what I meant.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: And what maximum current is required to be delivered to circuits at the output? What is your differential amplifier?

Comment: We have no idea what your diff amp is or its power requirements. If it only needs a few mA you're probably better off simply using a linear regulator, or even a series zener diode, rather than a buck converter if it's PSRR is any good.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on the current flowing through your circuit. If it's not very high, I would use a [linear regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator). However, I am not sure that any exist that output 20V. If you find any, then it would probably be okay. (Per @TonyM's comment, you could also use a variable regulator, line the [LM317](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf), as available from Texas Instruments or otherwise.)

If the current is high enough that you can't afford the heat generation due to the 4V voltage drop, then I would suggest a [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter), which is usually more efficient.

But really, I would have imagined that ICs have a little bit of leeway in terms of input voltage. Check your op-amp's datasheet and check. Since 24V is a pretty common voltage, I think that the op-amp IC would be able to have that as VCC.

Comment: For ones that exist and output 20 V, how about an adjustable regulator? :-)

Comment: @TonyM That's actually something I've absolutely forgotten about. Thanks for the idea!